# How to access data of a domain class in another model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a domain class like this,

```
public class DomainClassExample
{
        public int ClientAssessmentId { get; set; }

        public int IfaId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the data in this domain class in another model class as a list. 
Is there any way by which this can be done?

Comment: @DaggeJ I tried that, but it's getting null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the model to any other class as a proprty.

```
public class AnotherModelClassExample
{
    //...other properties

    public IEnumerable<DomainClassExample> DomainClassExampleList { get; set; }

   public AnotherModelClassExample(){
     DomainClassExampleList  = dbcontext.DomainClassExamples.ToList();
   }
}
```